# Python canvas doesn't draw multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating 2D game and when i am trying to add more than one wall they doesn't appear on canvas.

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

class wall:
  point1 = []
  point2 = []
  def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.point1.append(x1)
    self.point1.append(y1)
    self.point2.append(x2)
    self.point2.append(y2)
  def draw(self):
    self.canvas.create_line(self.point1[0], self.point1[1], self.point2[0], self.point2[1], width = 2)

walls = []
walls.append(wall(canvas, 90, 90, 100, 200))
walls.append(wall(canvas, 90, 90, 300, 100))

def update():
    for wall in walls:
        wall.draw()
    root.after(int(1000/60), update)
root.after(int(1000/60), update)
root.mainloop()
```

If I add them manually they are drawing both.

```py
canvas.create_line(90, 90, 100, 200, width = 2)
canvas.create_line(90, 90, 300, 100, width = 2)
```

Comment: couldn't be easier to keep it as `self.x1`, `self.y1`, `self.x2`, `self.y2` ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this part of your class `wall`:

```
class wall:
    point1 = []
    point2 = []
    ...
```

The lists `point1` and `point2` are defined as class attribute instead of instance attribute. So when you append new coordinates, the previous ones are still there.

To fix this, simply make `point` and `point2` instance attributes instead:

```
class wall:

    def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.point1 = []
        self.point2 = []
        ...
```

Or use the parameters directly:

```
class wall:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
    def draw(self):
       self.canvas.create_line(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, width = 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Instance attributes instead of Class attributes.

```
 class wall:
      def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
      def draw(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, width=2)
```

Comment: describe it. Code without explanation is less useful - even if it can be good idea.